# How to emulate dns failure in web browser?

Tags: dns, xfce

I have web app that I want to test for DNS failures because I think it don't handle them correctly, how can temporarly make all DNS lookup return error?

I'm using Xubuntu (XFCE).

Comment: `mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.bk` perhaps? :)

Comment: better yet, make it point to a live address without a DNS server **`:-)`**

Comment: @ThomasDickey that's what I just did, you can add this as an answer.

Comment: [Related question on Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/a/776191/354085)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@schaiba suggested renaming `/etc/resolv.conf`; a little better would be to make `/etc/resolv.conf` point to a live address without a DNS server running.  That is likely to reduce the timeouts.

Comment: You can make it point to `::1` or `127.0.0.1` which is your local machine, assuming you aren't running a DNS server on it.

Comment: I'm running DNS on more than one machine - OP may not, of course :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to test how your web browser reacts (whether it watches resolv.conf continuously for changes), you could try `ip route add 8.8.8.8/32 dev lo`, where `8.8.8.8` is the DNS server, for each DNS server. `ip route del` etc to revert.

Disclaimer: this won't work if you run `systemd-resolved` or `unbound` and the server is 127.0.0.1.  In that case the solution would be to apply `systemctl mask --runtime --now` to that service.

Warning: you should expect this to break networking horribly for the duration.

In some environments (network managed by single Windows Server?) the DNS machine may also be providing other vital services to your machine.  IP routing services by the target IP will not *necessarily* be interrupted... it should break hilariously if you had reverse-path-filtering enabled and your link requires Path MTU Discovery.